# activemq temporary queue not working

Tags: apache-camel, jms, activemq-classic, stomp

I need to implement "ActiveMq request response" like described at http://activemq.apache.org/how-should-i-implement-request-response-with-jms.html. The sender is written in ruby and using STOMP, the receiver is written in java and using JMS (camel).

The sender subscribes to a temporary queue and sends a message to another (static) queue with the JMSReplyTo header set to the name of the temporary queue (/temp-queue/fdc68b92-efe2-4d6f-b239-0539c4705e57, see https://activemq.apache.org/apollo/documentation/stomp-manual.html#Temporary_Destinations).

The receiver gets this message (with header JMSReplyTo=queue:///temp-queue/fdc68b92-efe2-4d6f-b239-0539c4705e57), processes it and puts the result into the reply-to queue. However the STOMP client doesn't receive anything. If I use a "normal" queue everything works fine.

How to get it working?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after lots of debugging it turns out the problem was setting the "JMSReplyTo" header directly and not the "reply-to" header.

It seems that activemq is rewriting the "reply-to" header internally as desired (to something like JMSReplyTo=temp-queue://ID:mybroker.local-42798-1516183213738-5:128503:1), but would pass "JMSReplyTo" unchanged.